# Do I have to provide callback in res.render() in EJS to catch error?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

This may be a dumb question as I am still learning `node.js/express.js` and `ejs`. Here is the calling format about the `res.render`:

```
res.render(view, [locals, [callback]])
```

I know that `res.render` can be called with `res.render(view)` or `res.render(view, data)`. In my app, there is a handler for unhandled rejection like below:

```
module.exports = function() {
    process.on("unhandledRejection", (ex) => {
        throw ex;
    });
};
```

In my case, do I have to provide `callback` to `res.render` to catch the `error`?